# form.serialize() doesn't send all values in the Ajax $.post()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting all the values from a form using `serialize()` and send them through a Ajax call using `$.post()` as follow:

```
$('button#btnBuscar').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    $.post('someRoute', $('#buscadorNorma').serialize(), 'json')
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data.entities);
            })
            .fail();
});
```

After click the submit button I check the POST data (in Firebug) send ​​to the route and I notice that only the last parameter was taken in this case `comite_tecnico` but what about the rest of them? Even if have values isn't send at all, why? I leave a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/omdpfzvy/1/) for testing purpose, can I get some help?

This is a image showing the results:

[image]

Note: for check the POST data use Firebug or any other tool!

Comment: your inputs got no `name` attributes. Add them and try again

Comment: @friedi you rock man, that's the problem and I didn't knew this before that `name` attr was mandatory anyway thx I learn something new today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name` attributes to your input elements like this:

```
<input type="text" id="codigo_norma" name="codigo_norma" class="form-control">
```